# Celery and Rabbit MQ Django

Tags: django, ubuntu, rabbitmq, celery

I installed Celery and RabbitMQ with the commands:
`pip install celery` and `sudo apt-get install rabbitmq`.
Celery doesn't work; I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/morilon/dj/shop/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 361, in find_app
    found = sym.app
AttributeError: module 'myshop' has no attribute 'app'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/morilon/dj/shop/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
 File "/home/morilon/dj/shop/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
    _main()
  File "/home/morilon/dj/shop/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 326, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/morilon/dj/shop/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/home/morilon/dj/shop/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 279, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/morilon/dj/shop/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 481, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/home/morilon/dj/shop/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 503, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/home/morilon/dj/shop/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 366, in find_app
    found = sym.celery
AttributeError: module 'myshop' has no attribute 'celery'
```

I don't understand what to do with this?

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Order

@task
def order_created(order_id):
    """
    Task to send an e-mail notification when an order is successfully created.
    """
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = 'Order nr. {}'.format(order.id)
    message = 'Dear {},\n\nYou have successfully placed an order. Your order id is {}.'.format(order.first_name,
                                                                             order.id)
    mail_sent = send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myshop.com', [order.email])
    return mail_sent
```

**celery.py**

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myshop.settings')

app = Celery('myshop')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

**init**.py

from .celery import app as celery_app

This project on GitHub https://github.com/Loctarogar/Django-by-Example

Comment: It looks like an import error stemming from you trying to do something like "from myshop.celery import..." . Can you post the rest of your Django code? Maybe the contents of the "myshop" app? Particularly if you have a tasks.py file

Comment: I try to learn Django with book "Django by Example". So all code i take from book.

Comment: Hmm okay, next question: it looks like that error might be coming from the line in your __init__.py file because it can't find the celery file. Can you post your project layout? Specifically, it'd be good to double check that your __init__.py file and your celery.py file are on the same level.

If they aren't, you don't need to move files around, but you do need to change the line "from .celery import app as celery_app". 

The "." means that the celery file is in the same folder as your init.py file, so if that's not the case, that's what's causing your error.

Comment: Hi I make a GitHub account . Here is a link for my project https://github.com/Loctarogar/Django-by-Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to double check spelling for file `celery.py` on your project directory where `settings.py` is located

Or you can follow [THIS](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) documentation for using celery with Django for more explanations

You can also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743267/celery-module-object-has-no-attribute-app-when-using-python-3)!

Answer (score 0):

Where's your `__init__.py` file which is importing the celery app? Is it in `shop/myshop/` directory? So it needs to be inside myshop app in order for celery app to be loaded at startup.

Comment: Hi can you help me? How can I close this question?